# Angular Changed the mat-label color to white, during error label is not changing to red color

Tags: angular, angular-material

I changed the mat-label color to white

When email validation failed then it is not showing the color as red.
If i dont change the color to white it is working properly. Tried  ngIf else and ternary operator etc but didnt work

I tried using class as well in that case my class is having more priority.

```
 <mat-label style="color:white">Email</mat-label>  
           and 
 <mat-label class="emailLabel">Email</mat-label>
```

Please find the screen shot
[custom class is applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tupKc.png)

Comment: Don't change it using the `style` attribute, because it has a higher priority than the class inferred styles. That's why your label keeps displaying white even in the error state. The red color is there (set by the error class), but because you use `style`, it is overridden with white. Try creating a class with `color: white` and see how that goes.

Comment: That I tried earlier and didnt work    .emailLabel {
  color:white;
}

Comment: Hello, where did you create your `emailLabel` class selector ? Depending on that, it will override the global material style as well.

Comment: I created emailLabel class inside  style tag of the same html file